# Proof of two properties of composistion

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just learning how to do proofs, and was wondering how to prove these two statements, regarding composition: $(g+h)\circ f = g \circ f + h \circ f$ and $\frac{1}{f\circ g} = \frac{1}{f}\circ g$.

Comment: Provide some details as to what you have tried to do. This will make it a lot easier to identify what your problem is and allow us to give you a good hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition of composition of functions, you know that $(f\circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$, and by definition of addition of functions, you know that $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$, both for all $x$.

Take some arbitrary $x$. Then
$$((g+h)\circ f)(x) = (g+h)(f(x)) = g(f(x)) + h(f(x)).$$
Also,
$$(g\circ f + h\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f)(x) + (h\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) + h(f(x)),$$
which is equal to the other expression above.
Thus $((g+h)\circ f)(x) = (g\circ f + h\circ f)(x)$ for all $x$, meaning that the two functions $(g+h)\circ f$ and $g\circ f + h\circ f$ are equal.

Similarly, we have for all $x$ that
$$\left(\frac{1}{f\circ g}\right)(x) = \frac{1}{(f\circ g)(x)} = \frac{1}{f(g(x))},$$
and also
$$\left(\frac{1}{f}\circ g\right)(x) = \left(\frac{1}{f}\right)(g(x)) = \frac{1}{f(g(x))}.$$
This shows that the functions $\frac{1}{f\circ g}$ and $\frac{1}{f}\circ g$ are equal.